# setting textarea text based on current input field

Tags: node.js, angularjs

I have two input fields

```
input(ng-model='form.firstName', name='firstName', id='familyName')
```

and

```
input(ng-model='form.lastName', name='lastName')
```

I also have a textarea field

```
textarea(id='fieldInfo', ng-model='fieldInfo', name='fieldInfo' cols='15', rows='10')
```

I would like to change the text in the TextArea to "Please enter your first name" when the focus or cursor is in the First Name input  and  change it to "Please enter your last name" when the is on the last name inout and it should be able to toggle as the user switches focus from first name to last name and last name to first name.

Any assistance will be much appreciated.

Melroy

Comment: By text in the fields, do you mean placeholders?

Comment: no, the actual text something like angular.element.val("Please enter your first name"). Eventually the text areas will become readonly and the input field focus will drive the text shown in the textarea field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [ng-focus](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angFocus) directive **will not work** for you if you are using one of the stable 1.0.x versions of AngularJS. However, I have created a [working CodePen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/sIjcK) of how you could do it without the [ng-focus](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angFocus) directive.

I created my own on-focus directive that evaluates an expression, which results in an update to the scope model being used by the textarea. I'm sure it could use some refinement, but the concept should still work for your application.

Comment: @Mel Glad to help. Would you mind marking my answer as Accepted so others seeing this know which resolution worked? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ngFocus directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angFocus) if you are using angular 1.2.0.

In your controller:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.text = "";
}]);
```

And in your view:

```
<input type="text" data-ng-model="form.name" ng-focus="text = 'Please enter your first name'" />
<input type="text" data-ng-model="form.last" ng-focus="text = 'Please enter your last name'" /> 

<textarea name="area" id="textarea" cols="30" rows="10"> {{ text }} </textarea>
```

You can check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/516/)

Edit: Wrong fiddle link

Comment: Thanks but it did not work for me. I think ng-focus is not working

Comment: It only works if you are using the 'unstable' angular version. What version are you using?

Comment: I am using angularjs 1.0.3

Comment: @Mel Have a look at my answer and see if it is an acceptable solution.

Comment: Then you should write your own solution. Take a look at @AdamThomas one!